# application stopped after some time while downloading image in slow connection

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my application i take an image and data from server. When internet connection is there image loaded properly. When internet connection slow down an application keeps on running and after sometime it stops suddenly.

This is `AsyncTask` to get image and data from server:

```
public void getPendingList() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Loading....");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            prepareList();
            getRegistrationDetails();
            getStateList();
            for (int i = 0; i < districts.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(districts.get(i));

                    String val1 = jsonObject.getString("OptionalParameter");
                    int val2 = jsonObject.getInt("ItemID");
                    String val3 = jsonObject.getString("Item_Description");
                    double val4 = jsonObject.getDouble("Item_Price");
                    String val5 = jsonObject.getString("Item_Code");
                    String val6 = jsonObject.getString("Item_Name");
                    String val7 = jsonObject.getString("ImageFinal");
                    String ItemCode = jsonObject.getString("Item_Code");

                    val7.replace("/", "");

                    listmodel.add(new Item_Master(val2, val3, val4, val6, val7, ItemCode));
                    listCountry.add("\u20B9" + val4);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return "response";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                if (!result.equals("NO_NETWORK")) {
                    mAdapter = new GridviewAdapter_Item_Master(FaramentView.getContext(), listmodel);
                    gridview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
                dismissDialog();
            }
        }.execute(null, null);
    }
}
```

After getting this data, I set `GridView` adapter in this data and image are set. I use Picasso library to download image and set with following code:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(list.get(position).getImagePath()).centerCrop()
    .resize(150, 150).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(view.imgViewFlag);
```

How to load image even in slow internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an **ANR** probably and that means you catch a **UI Timeout**, that because you trying to update an application component of UI in and `AsyncTask` (however keep in mind to manage background network processing in `doInBackground()` method); to update a UI application component you can use `Handlers` or updating it by `runOnUiThread()`